# Java Chat System

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I'm having problems with broadcasting the messages sent by each client. The server can receive each message from multiple clients but it cannot broadcast it. Error message says connection refused
Client:

```
    public void initializeConnection(){
    try {
        host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        try{
              // Create file 
              FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("src/out.txt", true);
              BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
              out.write(host.getHostAddress()+'\n');
              //Close the output stream
              out.close();
          }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }
        clientSocket = new Socket(host.getHostAddress(), port);
        outToServer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    }
    catch(IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==quit){
        try {
            outToServer.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==button){ 
        if(outMsgArea.getText()!=null || !outMsgArea.getText().equals("")){
            String message = outMsgArea.getText();
            outToServer.println(clientName+": "+message);
            outMsgArea.setText("");
        }
    }
}

public void run(){
    try {
        while(true){
            String message = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);
                inMsgArea.append(message+'\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RelayChatServer {
public static int port = 44442;
ServerSocket server;
public void listenSocket(){
  try{
    server = new ServerSocket(port);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Could not listen on port 4444");
    System.exit(-1);
  }
  while(true){
    ClientWorker w;
    try{
//server.accept returns a client connection
      w = new ClientWorker(server.accept());
      Thread t = new Thread(w);
      t.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Accept failed: 4444");
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }
}

protected void finalize(){
    //Objects created in run method are finalized when
    //program terminates and thread exits
         try{
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not close socket");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
      }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RelayChatServer().listenSocket();
}
```

}

```
class ClientWorker implements Runnable {
  private Socket client;

//Constructor
  ClientWorker(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public void run(){
    String line;
BufferedReader in = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
try{
  in = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
  //out = new 
  //  PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("in or out failed");
  System.exit(-1);
}

while(true){
  try{
    line = in.readLine();
//Send data back to client
    //out.println(line);
//Append data to text area
    if(line!=null && line!=""){
        System.out.println(line);
    try{
          // Open the file that is the first 
          // command line parameter
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("out.txt");
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
          String strLine;
          //Read File Line By Line
          Socket s;
          PrintWriter prnt;
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && (strLine = br.readLine()) != "")   {
          // Print the content on the console
              s = new Socket(strLine, 44441);
              prnt = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
              prnt.println(line);
              System.out.println(strLine);
              prnt.close();
              s.close();
          }
          //Close the input stream
          //inp.close();
            }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }
    }
   }catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Read failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
   }
}
  }

}
```

---

The `Exception` starts:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The expanded output looks like:

[image]

Comment: _Error message says connection refused Client:_ Can you give the stack trace?

Comment: https://imo.im/fd/A/gOeLB9QKrD/Untitled.png

Comment: @jayp:  Note that copy/pasting from the command line is a lot more useful than including an image of the same.  Do you know how to copy from the Windows CLI?

Comment: Umm.. good.  Note that you can edit your question any time to include that information.  Feel free to overwrite the edit where I transcribed the 1st line of the output. (hint-BIG-hint).

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat confused as to why you attempt to open a new socket (do you intend for this to be sent back to the client?) based on a string you read from a file. Perhaps

```
s = new Socket(strLine, 44441);
prnt = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
```

should be:

```
prnt = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
```

As currently I don't see where you are sending anything back to the client.

Edit: ok try something like the following:

```
static final ArrayList<ClientWorker> connectedClients = new ArrayList<ClientWorker>();
class ClientWorker implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    ClientWorker(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException ex) { /* do something sensible */ }
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(connectedClients) {
            connectedClients.add(this);
        }

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) { /* do something sensible */ }

        while (true) {
            try {
                String line = in.readLine();
                if (line != null && line != "") {
                    synchronized (connectedClients) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < connectedClients.size(); ++i){
                            ClientWorker client = connectedClients.get(i);
                            client.writer.println(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) { /* do something sensible */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say, I have a file. It has the host addresses of the clients who have connected to the server and I connect socket s to each client to broadcast the message. If I set it to client.getOutputStream(), I think it will send the message to itself

Comment: OK, creating new connections back to clients could be problematic if they have firewalls in place. This is probably why you are seeing the  connection refused error. Instead you'll want to use the Socket object for each client that you get when a connection is accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner. @.@ My clients are just waiting for servers to send something.If I don't set a new connection, then I can only send the message to the sender, not to the others. I'm confused. @.@

Comment: is it better to multicast instead? @.@

Comment: I'd avoid multicast. Take a look at my edit above, it may provide you with some ideas on how to approach this using your current classes...